# Are capers a substitute for pickles in a tartar sauce?

Tags: substitutions, pickles

Would capers work in place of the usual pickles in tartar sauce? I'm mostly curious and it might help other people who want to try this as well! I figure that it would add a tangy kind of aftertaste.

Comment: What type of sauce are you interested in? Tartare is not the same as tartar sauce.

Comment: @niall please be careful when you change spelling. In this question it made things confusing. :) tartar!=tartare

Comment: The spelling is good but are you talking about the cream-based sauce often paired with fish?

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about the fish sauce @catija

Comment: @Catija They're exactly the same thing, with tartare being the more correct spelling. Although I agree that this question is confusing as capers are one of the classic ingredients. Making it without would be an variation, not the other way round.

Comment: @Niall it was pointed out to me that this may be a US/UK difference. It's definitely "tartar" in the US. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tartar_sauce We generally respect the OP's spelling preferences when it comes to differing English spellings.

Comment: OK.Language confusion here --- how are capers, in the commonly sold form, not pickles?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the evergreen flower buds, not the cucumber type pickle

Comment: OH Ok, always assumed stuff coming in brine and/or acid in a glass was a pickle :)

Comment: No bother on my end

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I **love** capers and add them to different foods when I think it suits it. I'd much rather eat tartar (not tarter) sauce with capers than pickles in it. But them I'm not a fan of tartar sauce (maybe because of the pickles).  If you add capers, rinse them first to remove excess salt,  pat water off between a paper towel  and chop finely. I think a tiny bit of finely grated raw garlic would suit it nicely. Let the flavours meld together in the fridge for a few hours too.

Answer (score 4):

Both capers **&** pickles is not unheard of, as in [the sauce tartare](http://www.architectmom.com/2012/02/fancy-up-your-fish-filet-sandwiches-with-julia-childs-sauce-tartare/) recipe in Mastering the Art of French Cooking. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tartar_sauce) also thinks capers and pickles are a common combination in tartar sauce.

I think it would probably be a good sauce with the pickles swapped out, but I've only added capers to the pickles, not substitued.